# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined when trying to direct message a user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a system that allows my bot to direct message people, but an error always seems to come up when trying to direct message a user that has not sent a dm to the bot since it was last restarted.

This is the error that I keep on getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

This is the important code:

```
            message.channel.send({ embed: dmattempt }).then(sentMessage => {
                try {
                    // Tries to send a message to the user
                    const themsguser = client.users.cache.get(dmId);
                    themsguser.send(`${sentence}`);
```

Here is the code for the entire command:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    function directMsgUser(dmUser, dmCommand, dmId) {
        if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}${dmCommand}`)) {
            let sentence = message.content.split(' ');
            sentence.shift();
            sentence = sentence.join(' ');
            const dmattempt = {
                color: [0, 0, 255],
                title: `trying to direct message ${dmUser}`,
                description: 'please wait',
                footer: {
                    text: `message sending from ${message.author.tag}`,
                    icon_url: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,
                },
            };
            const msgsent = {
                color: [0, 255, 0],
                title: `message sent to ${dmUser}`,
                description: `message content: ${sentence}`,
                footer: {
                    text: `message sent by ${message.author.tag}`,
                    icon_url: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,
                },
            };
            // Sends a message confirming that the message is trying to be sent
            console.log(`Trying to direct message ${dmUser}`);
            message.channel.send({ embed: dmattempt }).then(sentMessage => {
                try {
                    // Tries to send a message to the user
                    const themsguser = client.users.cache.get(dmId);
                    themsguser.send(`${sentence}`);
                    // Edits the message to verify it was sent
                    sentMessage.edit({ embed: msgsent });
                    console.log('Message sent!');
                }
                catch (error) {
                    // Edits the message to verify something went wrong
                    const errorembed = {
                        color: [255, 0, 0],
                        title: 'error!',
                        description: `There was an error messaging ${dmUser}`,
                        footer: {
                            text: `message sent by ${message.author.tag}`,
                            icon_url: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,
                        },
                    };
                    sentMessage.edit({ embed: errorembed });
                    console.error(error);
                    console.error('There was an error sending a direct message.');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}dm`)) {
        directMsgUser(theUser, theCommand, idforuser);
    }
});
```

Note that this command works if the user the message is getting sent to has sent a dm to the bot since it has been restarted.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the problem is that since you are attempting to get the user from the cache, the user may not be in the cache yet. And this would make sense with why it works if the user has previously sent the bot a DM already, because doing so would add them to the cache. But if they haven't DM'd the bot before, then they might not be in the user cache yet.

You could use `.fetch(id, cache)` instead of `.cache.get(id)` in order to ensure that you fetch the user, even if they are not in the cache yet:

```
client.users.fetch(dmID, true).then(themsguser => {
    themsguser.send(`${sentence}`);
});
```

This method will make the bot first check if the user with ID `dmID` is in the cache. If it is, it will use the value in the cache. If it isn't, it will fetch the user by directly requesting the Discord API. And because we set the second argument of our `.fetch()` to `true`, the method will also add our user to the cache after fetching it (if it wasn't already in the cache), therefore preventing the need to repeatedly request data from the API.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch